# Редактирование элемента в односвязном списке

Tags: c++

Вот моя реализация односвязного списка, с информационными полями: Город и 3 названия района. Есть функции ввода-вывода, удаления элемента по номеру, у меня вызвала функция редактирования элемента. Как я понял, не нужно удалять элемент, нужно менять данные, но до меня так и не дошло, как это реализовать. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

```
/*Вот содержание файла ss.txt:
gorod1
rayon1
rayon2
rayon3
gorod2
rayon11
rayon22
rayon33
gorod3
rayon111
rayon222
rayon333*/




#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct List {
    string name;
    char rayon1[20];
    char rayon2[20];
    char rayon3[20];
    List *nxt;
};
void vvod(List* head, int n, int size) {
    List* tmp = head;
    ifstream fin("ss.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (i) {
            tmp->nxt = new List;
            tmp = tmp->nxt;
            size++;
        }
        fin >> tmp->name;
        fin >> tmp->rayon1;
        fin >> tmp->rayon2;
        fin >> tmp->rayon3;
        tmp->nxt = NULL;
    }
    fin.close();
}
void edit(List *head, string name, int pos, string gorod){
for(int i =0;i<pos;++i){
head = head->nxt;
head->name = gorod;
}
void remove_element(List *head, int n, int size)
{

    List* tmp = head;
    int i = 0;
    List* prev = NULL;
    if (head!=NULL && n < size)
    {
        while(tmp && i < n-1) {
            ++i;
            prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->nxt;
        }
        if (!tmp) {
            return;
        }
        if (head == tmp)
        {
            head = tmp->nxt;
        }
        else
        {
            if (prev) {
                prev->nxt = tmp->nxt;
            }
        }   
        size--;
        delete(tmp);
    }
}
    void vivod(List *head, int n) {
        List* tmp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            cout << " NOMER " << i + 1 << endl;
            cout << tmp->name;
            cout << endl;
            cout << tmp->rayon1 << "   " << tmp->rayon2 << "   " << tmp->rayon3 << endl;
            tmp = tmp->nxt;
        }
    }
int main()
{
    List *head = new List;
    int n=0;
    string stroka;
    int z = 0;
    cout << " Vvedite kolichestvo gorodov " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int size = n;
    vvod(head, n, size);
    cout << "size:" << size << endl;
    vivod(head, n);
    goto label1;
    label1:
    cout << "Cho udalit? " << endl;
    cin >> z;
    remove_element(head, z, size);
    vivod(head, n);
    system("pause");
}
 //Вопрос решен
```

Comment: Ну то есть очевидно, что автор вопроса этого кода не писал - код "позаимствованный". Не может быть такого, чтобы человек, написавший этот код, не мог при этом "просто менять данные".

Comment: Код то я писал сам, просто не понял как реализовать смену данных эту, плюс, если заметите, у меня не все гладко с удалением. В теории я понял как поменять их, просто не дошел до реализации и сдался, решил задать вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* zbPos: нулевая позиция элемента редактировать */
void redaktirovat(int zbPos, List *head, string name, char rayon1[20], char rayon2[20],
                                        char rayon3[20])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < zbPos; ++i)
        head = head->next;

    head->name = name;
    strcpy(head->rayon1, rayon1);
    strcpy(head->rayon2, rayon2);
    strcpy(head->rayon3, rayon3);
}
```